# Detect data-part on widget

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0

I have a widget that allow me to pass a data-part. Based on if I informed a data-part to a instance of that widget, I want to show/hide something from the widget. So it is possible to detect on my widget viewmodel if the was specified something for a data-part?

Answer (score 0):

The `activate` method of a widget's view model gets passed a `settings` object (this code is from the [Durandal sample application](http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#widgets)):

```
ctor.prototype.activate = function(settings) {
    this.settings = settings;
};
```

Within the `settings` object, you can inspect the `parent` property which will give you the node that the widget was bound to:

```
<div data-bind="expander:{items:projects}"></div>
```

That should give you access to the `data-part` attribute on the node.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `composition` module's `getParts` method within the widget's `attached` event callback.  See http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api#module/composition/method/getParts

```
// MyWidget viewmodel
define(['durandal/composition'], function (composition) {
    var widget = function() {
        var plugin = this;

        plugin.showSomething = function () {
            something.show();
        );

        // See http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM    
        plugin.attached = function (view, parent) {
            // See http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api#module/composition/method/getParts
            var dataparts = composition.getParts(view);

            plugin.parts = {
                $partOne: $(dataparts.datapartnameone),
                $partTwo: $(dataparts.datapartnametwo)
            };

            if (plugin.parts.$partOne) {
                // An element with data-part="datapartnameone" was found in the host container
                plugin.showSomething();
            }
        };
    };

    return widget;
});

// Example host container

<div data-bind="MyWidget: {}">
    <span data-part="datapartnameone">My data-part</span>
</div>
```